# Find the value of $g'(0)+g'(\pi/4)$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

> Suppose $$\int \frac{1-7\cos^2 x}{\sin ^7 x \cos^2 x}dx=\frac{g(x)}{\sin^7 x}+C$$ where $C$ is arbitrary constant of integration. Then find the value of  $g'(0)+g'(\pi/4)$.

Now, if I directly differentiate the expression, it doesn't give me anything because of terms like $\cot x$ come in it and at $x=0$, they are not defined. And if the way to go is integration, I am unable to integrate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First split the integral in two parts:
$$I=\int \frac{1-7\cos^2 x}{\sin ^7 x \cos^2 x}dx=\int\csc^7x\sec^2x\space dx-\int7\csc^7x \space dx$$

Now in the first part of the integral apply integration by parts and notice that the second integral cancels out leaving us with only :

$$I=\tan x\csc^7x+C$$

Looks easy from here ;)